# flutter_webview_plugin fullscreen option disabled on android

Tags: android, flutter, video, mp4, vimeo

I'm trying to show a video from Vimeo in a container.

Here is the code:

```
Widget videoBox() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (9 / 16),
      child: WebviewScaffold(
        url: myVideolink,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        allowFileURLs: true,
        withJavascript: true,
        withZoom: false,
        displayZoomControls: false,
        enableAppScheme: true,
        supportMultipleWindows: true,
        scrollBar: false,
      ),
    );
  }
```

myVideoLink is https://player.vimeo.com/video/*vimeovideoid*

In iOS everything works just fine, in Android the fullscreen button is not present.
I've tried to replace myVideoLink with the link to the actual .mp4 file, it still works in iOS. In Android the fullscreen button is present but grayed out.

Can you please help me?

Thanks